# pre/post build event Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio

How can I write pre build event, that will copy file from solution folder to document folder. Path to document can change(solution may be run on different machine)

Comment: where does the path and document get stored ? in the app.config ?

Comment: You only care about one path, the one you need to debug your code.  Whatever happens on a different machine is determined by the installer.  Little reason to make it hard to find, %programdata% is the standard folder.

Answer (score 0):

you can use xcopy or copy command from DOS in pre or post build events. I have used that to maintain multiple web config files in asp.net applications and multiple releases with different configuration in desktop applications.

for example: `xcopy "$(TargetPath)" "$(SolutionDir)$(OutDir)" /i /d /y`

Also check out this article, this may help
http://geekswithblogs.net/dchestnutt/archive/2006/05/30/80113.aspx

Comment: But out put direction may be C:\Users\user1, C:\Users\user2 C:\User\SubUsers\User1 according to machines setting

Comment: @Kumiho - require that the different machines have an environment variable pointing to the correct place, and use that in your xcopy command.

Comment: But if I dont want to type the path on every machines.
Is it possible